# How to create a nested functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, datatables

I'm building own API to generate dynamic table in JS (I know about dataTables). I need some another functions but the scheme of work is similar.

I'm wondering how works a function e.g. data() in dataTables while toArray() is inside this function?

for example: when I want to get data I need to call dataTable().data() but if I want to get data as JS array I call dataTable().data().toArray();

I try in this case at shown below:

```
return {
   data: {
      toArray: () => {
         return myArray;
      }
   }
}
```

My above code is works but how can I call a data() function that it return to me another data without call toArray() function?

I want to get this effect:

1. MydataTable.data() - I get array of HTML object
2. MydataTable.data().toArray() - I get JS array from HTML objects

**prototype**

```
function oData() {
    this.arr = Obj.HTML;
}
    
oData.prototype.data = () => {
    return Obj.HTML;
}
    
oData.prototype.toArray = () => {
    return Obj.data;
}

let obj = new oData();
```

obj.data() return array of HTML objects

obj.toArray() return array of data objects

but I want use obj.data().toArray() to get array of data objects

Comment: You can't do that. For `MydataTable.data().toArray()` to work, the `data()` function has to return an object, not an array.

Comment: Why not just use two different methods?

Comment: the data() should return the array of HTML object. and you cad add a prototype to Array that will be toArray()

Comment: I updated my question. Barmar Your right, data() is an object, not function. Mordy Stern, can you show me the easiest way how can I to do? I read about prototypes but I don't know how to use them in my case.

Comment: @SeaDog can you give us an example of what `data()` returns, and example of what `data().toArray()` should return?

Comment: @Mordy Stern, data() is not a function while data.toArray() return an array of object. I can't understand how it work in dataTables just like function after function but with modernized data e.g.: dataTables().rows().data();

Comment: @Mordy Stern, I updated my question.

Comment: About how DataTable does it, read the description here https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Api

Comment: I think I already know, it was about chaining methods https://schier.co/blog/method-chaining-in-javascript